# Python Pandas: remove duplicate in csv file with no headings

Tags: python, pandas

sorry for the dumb question I am new to python and pandas.

Imagine I've got a csv file with some data for every row, for example :

```
data1, data2, data3, data4
```

There are no headings, just data, and I need to remove some rows inside such file if

```
(row1.data3 and row1.data4) == (row2.data3 and row2.data4)
```

the entire row gets removed.

How can I achieve that?

I did try to use remove_duplicates but without headings I don't know how to do it.

cheers

Comment: Just to make sure, you're resetting the dataframe after remove_duplicates, right? remove_duplicates does not work inplace unless you ask it to.

Headings wouldn't matter much here. If a row is a duplicate of another row and they are the same data type remove_duplicates should remove it.

Comment: Show us the code you have so far.

Answer (score 3):

Let's say you happen to have a `df` without header:

```
df = pd.read_csv("./try.csv", header=None)
df
# The first row is integers inserted instead of missing column names 
    0   1   2
0   1   1   1
1   1   1   1
2   2   1   3
3   2   1   3
4   3   2   3
5   3   3   3
```

Then, you can `drop_duplicates` on subsets of columns:

```
df.drop_duplicates([0])
    0   1   2
0   1   1   1
2   2   1   3
4   3   2   3
```

or

```
df.drop_duplicates([0,1])

    0   1   2
0   1   1   1
2   2   1   3
4   3   2   3
5   3   3   3
```

Do not forget to assign the result to a new variable or add `inplace=True`

Comment: @user1583007 Why not accept the answer if it worked for you?